# Saved tab including synonym + master shows zero results

Tags: bug, tag-synonym-process, new-nav

I have saved a [tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3%20chef%20gerrit%20zabbix%20jenkins%20jenkins-workflow%20jenkins-pipeline?filter=all&sort=active&mode=any) containing a search query which includes [jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline) and [jenkins-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-workflow) (with *any* option set).

Since the [synonym request](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jenkins-pipeline/synonyms) for [jenkins-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-workflow) → [jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline) was recently approved, my stored tab does not show any results.

There seems to be a bug regarding handling of the synonyms. If I enter

```
[jenkins-pipeline] [jenkins-workflow]
```

into the search field, the synonym [jenkins-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-workflow) is automatically dropped and results for [jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline) are shown. This does *not* happen for saved tabs.
[image]